# Configure Google Apps Gmail to get email from external server

Tags: gmail

I have a big question. I search in Google Help pages, but honestly, their system for help is very bad.

So, lets go to the point.

I have a domain, in this case lets say it is example.com.br, in an older host company. Last week I change the host company.

I could access my emails in via google with an account like "rafael@example.com.br". Now that I change the host company, I can't get any emails. I can't find a place to change the POP configuration in my google account.

Thanks for help!

Comment: settings -> accounts and import.

Comment: I tried that, but my google account has the same username as the email I want to import, so google doesn't allow me to create a new import account.